# How to drop overloaded functions in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have faced this question during an interview very recently. Please hep me on this. Let us say there are two functions in our schema the prototypes of  which are as follows,

1. `display(a varchar2, b number)`
2. `display(c varchar2, d varchar2, e number)`

and I issue the following statement

```
drop function display;
```

which function will be dropped?

Comment: You cannot create two stand-alone stored procedures/functions with the same name in the same schema, even if the number and data types of their actual parameters differ. You can have overloaded version of a function only in a package, or as an operator with multiple bindings(can be considered as an overloaded version of a function). So probably that was a trick question.

Comment: Are you sure that was an interview for Oracle? To my knowledge only Postgres and DB2 allow this kind of function overloading (for standalone functions/procedures)

Comment: I wonder what kind of conclusions a recruiter would make from that kind of questions...

Answer (score 0):

overloading means use of same subprograms to call different subprograms. this is an example

```
declare

    x number;        
    y number;

    function findenqno (fname1 varchar2) return number is --–function 1        
        enqno1 number (10);       
    begin
        select enquiryno        
        into enqno1       
        from enquiry        
        where fname = fname1;
        return(enqno1);
    end;

    function findenqno (refcode1 number) return number is --–function 2
        enqno1 number (10);
    begin
        select enquiryno    
        into enqno1
        from enquiry
        where refcode = refcode1;
        return (enqno1);
    end;        
begin
-- You call the function as:
X := findenqno ('ANIL');
    dbms_output.put_line('using name '||x);   
    Y := findenqno (1002);
    dbms_output.put_line('using refcode '||y);
end;
/
```

this is not a standlone subprogram so there is no point droping a overloaded function .

as it is not written in the db.